# Why my state is empty when I try to access it from a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this room component for video chat, it has two states, `players` to hold all elements, it is an array of nodes, each is a div, created when a user joins the room (this happens inside `useEffect`) and `videoInDisplayFrame`  to hold the current element in display frame, when the user clicks on a specific player we set this one to `videoInDisplayFrame`.

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import styles from "./Room.module.css";

export default function Room() {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
  const [videoInDisplayFrame, setVideoInDisplayFrame] = useState(null);

  const displayFrame_ref = useRef();
  const streams__container_ref = useRef();

  let expandVideoFrame = (e) => {
    console.log("expandVideoFrame is running... players:",players,"videoInDisplayFrame:",videoInDisplayFrame);

    displayFrame_ref.current.style.display = "block";

    //if videoInDisplayFrame is not null
    if (videoInDisplayFrame) {
      // add videoInDisplayFrame to players
      setPlayers((prev) => [...prev, videoInDisplayFrame]);
    }
    // find from players the one with the same id as e.currentTarget
    const newVideoInDisplayFrame = players.find((element) => 
      element.props.id === e.currentTarget.id;
    );
    // then if it exists, add it to videoInDisplayFrame
    if (newVideoInDisplayFrame) {
      setVideoInDisplayFrame(newVideoInDisplayFrame);
    }
  };

  let hideDisplayFrame = () => {
    console.log("hideDisplayFrame is running... players:",players,"videoInDisplayFrame:",videoInDisplayFrame);

    displayFrame_ref.current.style.display = null;

    // add videoInDisplayFrame to players
    setPlayers([...players, videoInDisplayFrame]);

    // set videoInDisplayFrame to null
    setVideoInDisplayFrame(null);
    
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect is running...");
    // after component first mount
    let uid = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000));
    // create JSX element
    let player = (
      <div
        // ref={videoFrames_refs[videoFrames_refs.length]}
        className={styles.video__container}
        id={`user-container-${uid}`}
        onClick={expandVideoFrame}
      >
        <div className={styles.video_player} id={`user-${uid}`}></div>
      </div>
    );
    // add it to players
    setPlayers((prev) => [...prev, player]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("This is a new render... players: ",players,"and videoInDisplayFrame: ",videoInDisplayFrame)}
      <section
        className={styles.stream__container}
      >
        <div
          ref={displayFrame_ref}
          id="stream__box"
          className={styles.stream__box}
          onClick={hideDisplayFrame}
        >
          {videoInDisplayFrame}
        </div>

        <div
          ref={streams__container_ref}
          className={styles.streams__container}
        >
          {/* display players inside JSX */}
          {players.map((element, index) => (
            <div key={index}>{element}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

when I mount the components for the first time and then click on the only player I have to display it, I can see that my `players` state is an empty array, I expected it to contain the element so I can remove it and set it inside `videoInDisplayFrame` because `useEffect` should update it so the component rerenders and the state is updated before I click, I even added this button

```html
<button
  onClick={() => {
   console.log("current state... players: ",players,"videoInDisplayFrame:",videoInDisplayFrame);
  }}
 >
current state
</button>
```

to be able to see the state at any moment and the output was confusing :
[image]

as you can see, even when I clicked on the button to see the state before `expandVideoFrame` and after it and it is not empty event when I click to run `hideDisplayFrame` after this, `players` is not empty so why it is when `expandVideoFrame` runs?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you store the HTML with the function `expandVideoFrame` in it.

Thus when it runs the first `useEffect` it stores the function without any players. That's why you always have an empty array.

You have to store only the data you want and render the HTML in the return of your component.

Comment: From what I understand when you store your players with the HTML, it stores the function also. But at that point the players array is empty.

Comment: ah! yes, does this means that when I run its `expandVideoFrame` function it will not look at the current value of the state but at what it was when this latter was created?

Comment: Yep that's what I understood.

Comment: yes you are right!